# String Array wont populate with values

Tags: java, arrays

this code is supposed to fill the array gameResult with 1s and 0s, when the playGame method is called, but the array wont fill with the values i try to assign to it, not sure why this is happening, i tried using an array of ints and the result is the same the array still doesnt populate with values.

```
import java.util.Scanner;



class Main { //Assignment1.java 
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int number;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number from 1-100: ");
    number = keyboard.nextInt();

    playGame(number);


    keyboard.close();

 }
    public static String[] playGame( int chosenNumber ){
      String[] gameResult = new String[9];
      int upper = 100;
      int lower = 1;
      int middle;

      for(int i=0;i<=7;i++){
        middle = (lower+upper)/2;
          if (chosenNumber < middle) {
            gameResult[i]="0";
            upper = middle;
       }
      else{
          gameResult[i]="1";
          lower = middle;
      }    
  }
  System.out.format("Chosen integer %3d: ", chosenNumber);
  System.out.println();
  return gameResult;
}
```

Comment: You aren't displaying the array or storing it anywhere.

Comment: When you step through the code in your debugger what do you see?

Comment: i dont use the debugger, but what would you recommend for ide for java?

Comment: @Rusty : You can use eclipse, intellij to name some popular ones.

Comment: thanks! it worked also, didnt realize what i was doing but now i understand what went wrong, thank you everyone for helping

Answer (score 1):

You aren't displaying or using the array anywhere (you are assigning values to some of the indices) I have modified the main method just to print the returned array to display the values

```
class Main { //Assignment1.java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int number;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number from 1-100: ");
    number = keyboard.nextInt();


    String[] arr = playGame(number);
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        System.out.println(arr[i]);

    keyboard.close();

}

public static String[] playGame(int chosenNumber) {
    String[] gameResult = new String[9];
    int upper = 100;
    int lower = 1;
    int middle;

    for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
        middle = (lower + upper) / 2;
        if (chosenNumber < middle) {
            gameResult[i] = "0";
            upper = middle;
        } else {
            gameResult[i] = "1";
            lower = middle;
        }
    }
    System.out.format("Chosen integer %3d: ", chosenNumber);
    System.out.println();
    return gameResult;
}
```

Hope it helps.